# React-Native: Unable to recreate Android & iOS Folders

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am having issues with recreating the Android and iOS folders, as the commands "eject" no longer work, and neither does:

```
react-native upgrade --legacy true
```

I don't really want to create a new project to just copy-paste the files over, as I am creating a template/boilerplate project, and changing the name of the project requires deleting and recreating the two folders. It would seem like a tedious extra step to using the template.

Are there other commands that are not yet documented/found in `react-native --help`?

Best Regards

Comment: what happens for `react-native upgrade --legacy true`?

Comment: error: unknown option `--legacy'  

The command worked before, then I removed node_modules and reran ```npm i```  
Now it doesn't. I checked the difference between 0.61.2 React Native, and it seems like it changed quite a bit (More dependencies) although it stated they both were 0.61.2.

Does react-native upgrade --legacy true work for you?

Comment: did you try using yarn? install yarn and delete node modules folder and run `yarn install` in the project directory and then try `react-native upgrade --legacy true` again. tell me what happens

Comment: Same error, removed node_modules, installed yarn, ran ```yarn install```, then ```react-native upgrade --legacy true``` and got:    error: unknown option `--legacy'. Does it work for you in a new project?